# BeautifulSoup or urllib.request in python, returns different on different machines

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

So I have written this simple piece of script, but it only works on my linux machine and not Windows 8.1

The code is::

```
BASE_URL = "http://www.betfair.com/exchange/football/event?id="+ str(matchId)
html = urlopen(BASE_URL).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
homeScore = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "home-score"})[0].text
```

On my Windows 8 machine it returns this from the urlopen:

```
html    bytes: b'\\n\\n    \\n    <!DOCTYPE html>\\n\\n    <!--[if IE]><![endif]-->\\n\\n    <!--[if       IE 9]>\\n    <html class="ie9" lang="da-DK"><![endif]--><!--[if IE 8]>\\n    <html class="ie8"   lang="da-DK"><![endif]--><!--[if IE 7]>\\n    <html class="ie7" lang="da-DK"><![endif]--><!--[if lt IE 7]>\\n    <html class="ie6" lang="da-DK"><![endif]-->\\n    <!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->\\n    <html lang="da-DK">\\n    <!--<![endif]-->\\n    <head>\\n        <meta name="description" content="San Luis de Quillota v Deportes Temuco ma 15 dec 2014 11:00PM - betting odds. Find markedets bedste spil, samt links til andre ressourcer.">\\n    <meta charset="utf-8">\\n    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no"/>\\n    <base href="http://www.betfair.com/exchange/"/>\\n    <title>        San Luis de Quillota v Deportes Temuco betting odds | Chilean Primera B | betfair.com\\n</title>\\n\\n    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//sn4.cdnbf.net/exchange/favicon_13031_....
```

The dots is the actual ending on the output.  How can I make the same code work on both systems?

Edit: My Windows 8 is python 3.4 and linux is python 3.2

Comment: What do you get from the code on linux? What is difference of html data between on Win8.1 and on linux?

Comment: my linux machines gets the full html of the site, and it is able to find the expected span with the right class

Answer (score 0):

If you have the opportunity, you should consider using [`Requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) instead of `urllib`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'http://www.betfair.com/exchange/football/event'
params = { 'id': str(matchId) }
r = requests.get(base_url, params=params)
html = r.content.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
```

Provided that `requests` is build to handle several formats seamlessly, it *should* work on each of your platforms. If that's not the case, test different parameters for `r.content.decode()` but anyway, it will be much easier than with using `urllib`.